# iOS9 NSDefaultRunLoopMode does not listen to didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken delegate

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsrunloop, runloop

In iOS 9 the

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:timeoutDate];
```

does not listen to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` or `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` delegate, however it listens to `applicationDidEnterBackground` and other `UIApplication` delegates. It was working fine for iOS 7 and iOS 8.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self waitForCompletion:30];
   });
  return YES;
}

- (bool)waitForCompletion:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutSecs {
   NSDate *timeoutDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeoutSecs];
   do {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:timeoutDate];
    if ([timeoutDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0)
        break;
   } while (!_done);
   return _done;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
   // send device token to server
   _done = true;
}
```

`application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` always calls after 30 seconds (timeout value).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that loop?

Comment: blocking the main thread until device token is received or timeout occurred (in my case its 30 seconds).

Comment: Sure, I see that. But why do you want to block the main thread (which is IMHO not a good design)?